# How do I actually use an imported JS script in my LWC?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

Let's say I have a really basic script as a static resource in my org:

helloWorld.js

```
function helloWorld() {
    alert("Hello World!");
}
```

and I import it to my component as per below:

myComponent.js

```
import helloWorld from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/helloWorld';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class TechDocSelfServe extends LightningElement {

    connectedCallback() {
        loadScript(this,helloWorld)
            .then(() => {
                alert('loaded!');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('error -> ' + error);
            });
    }
}
```

How would I actually call the imported method? I can't see anything in the documentation that explains this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to use a script function, it needs to be exported. For static resources, this means using the window global object. Note that because of how LWC works, the methods won't leak to other components (each component gets its own window object).

```
window.helloWorld = function() {
    alert("Hello World!");
}
```

And to call it:

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import HELLOWORLD from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/helloworld";

export default class Q317576 extends LightningElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    loadScript(this, HELLOWORLD).then(() => {
      helloWorld();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox

Comment: @altius_rup I just checked, and `window` is working for me. Do you have any documentation that demonstrates this? Or was it a problem you ran in to?

Comment: @sfdcfox I'm working with D3js on platform. Here is an example of d3-context-menu 2.1.0 which adds itself as 'd3.contextMenu' (line 17) : https://github.com/patorjk/d3-context-menu/blob/419c584c5125453e203e661751636903e46c3f27/js/d3-context-menu.js#L17.  I've just realized that 'root' is a local variable here : duh ! Sorry about the mistake, I will delete my previous comment.  I will let you delete yours.

Comment: @altius_rup no worries, it happens to the best of us.

Answer (score -2):

You can have a look at this, you should get the js into this using loadscript and then use it

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library

Comment: I have managed to load the script. In the documentation they seem to just use `d3.functionHere;` but it is never instantiated so I am wondering how to do this. How would I actually call my function `helloWorld()`?

Comment: Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, helloWorld  + '/helloWorld.js')
        ])
            .then(() => {
                alert('yes it is working');
            });                                           Can you try this?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding. The script itself loads successfully. In my original question I am asking how to call the functions within the script. How do I call the `helloWorld()` function within `helloWorld.js`. I can load the script fine into my component.